# Where should I ask about MDM policies used with 802.1x Wi-Fi?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Meta: Due to the cross-purpose functions of servers and networking, I have no idea if this question is more suitable on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour), or the [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) Stack Exchange. Any ideas? I am leaning in the direction of Server Fault.

---

**Can 802.1x Wi-Fi [BYOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_your_own_device) users be required to accept an [MDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) policy?**

I'm dipping my toe into 802.1x Wi-Fi. I currently have my Cisco 5520 Wi-Fi controller linked to Microsoft NPS (Network Policy Server, their form of RADIUS) and using login and password accounts stored in Active Directory. This is working properly.

Is there a way to also require that personal BYOD smartphones must accept an organizational MDM policy to join the 802.1x Wi-Fi, and to somehow check that the policy is still active to continue to have Wi-Fi access once joined?

It's not at all clear to me how this would work or if it can be done at all.

- Where would the MDM policy be coming from?
- How do I link an MDM policy to the active directory Wi-Fi account logins?
- How would the Wi-Fi controller or NPS be able to verify that the MDM policy is active on the personal BYOD?

Also, is it possible to have an MDM policy that is only only active on BYOD when using the 802.1x Wi-Fi for our organization? But otherwise the MDM policy is inactive when using only cellular data, or other non 802.1x Wi-Fi SSIDs?

Comment: Six questions in one post is probably way too many. Where is the canonical meta question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't know what a CMQ is, or why it matters when asking for topicality help on Meta.

Comment: Network Engineering is most likely to get you high-quality answers for these kinds of questions. Information Security would only be on-topic if the question is about the security aspects of this protocol.